How to automatically migrate from `styleUrls` to `styleUrl` in Angular 17 components?
Angular 17 has introduced styleUrl as a convenience for cases where there's only one stylesheet in the @Component's styleUrls.
How to automatically migrate  from styleUrls to styleUrl in an existing codebase?

How about Replace all with regex? The following regex searches for all arrays that contain only one string (assuming you use single quotes).
Search: styleUrls: \['([^']*)'\],
Replace: styleUrl: '$1',
